# overflow possibilities in modular exponentiation by squaring

Tags: c++, algorithm, primes, exponentiation

I am looking to implement the [fermat's little theorem](http://theoremoftheweek.wordpress.com/2010/01/20/theorem-14-fermats-little-theorem/) for prime testing. Here's the code I have written:

```
lld expo(lld n, lld p) //2^p mod n
{
    if(p==0)
        return 1;
    lld exp=expo(n,p/2);
    if(p%2==0)
        return (exp*exp)%n;
    else
        return (((exp*exp)%n)*2)%n;
}

bool ifPseudoPrime(lld n)
{
    if(expo(n,n)==2)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

**NOTE:** I took the value of `a(<=n-1)` as `2`.

Now, the number n can go as large as `10^18`. This means that variable `exp` can reach values near `10^18`. Which further implies that the expression `(exp*exp)` can reach as high as `10^36` hence causing overflow. How do I avoid this.

I tested this and it ran fine till `10^9`. I am using **C++**

Comment: @moonshadow: please don't.

Comment: @n.m. What's the problem with GMP?

Comment: @moonshadow actually I'm up for a competition and I faced this problem. I can't use any external libraries like GMP.

Comment: @DanielFischer: No problem with GMP per se, but in this task it is way overkill.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the modulus is close to the limit of the largest integer type you can use, things get somewhat complicated. If you can't use a library that implements biginteger arithmetic, you can roll a modular multiplication yourself by splitting the factors in low-order and high-order parts.

If the modulus `m` is so large that `2*(m-1)` overflows, things get really fussy, but if `2*(m-1)` doesn't overflow, it's bearable.

Let us suppose you have and use a 64-bit unsigned integer type.

You can calculate the modular product by splitting the factors into low and high 32 bits, the product then splits into

```
a = a1 + (a2 << 32)    // 0 <= a1, a2 < (1 << 32)
b = b1 + (b2 << 32)    // 0 <= b1, b2 < (1 << 32)
a*b = a1*b1 + (a1*b2 << 32) + (a2*b1 << 32) + (a2*b2 << 64)
```

To calculate `a*b (mod m)` with `m <= (1 << 63)`, reduce each of the four products modulo `m`,

```
p1 = (a1*b1) % m;
p2 = (a1*b2) % m;
p3 = (a2*b1) % m;
p4 = (a2*b2) % m;
```

and the simplest way to incorporate the shifts is

```
for(i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
    p2 *= 2;
    if (p2 >= m) p2 -= m;
}
```

the same for `p3` and with 64 iterations for `p4`. Then

```
s = p1+p2;
if (s >= m) s -= m;
s += p3;
if (s >= m) s -= m;
s += p4;
if (s >= m) s -= m;
return s;
```

That way is not very fast, but for the few multiplications needed here, it may be fast enough. A small speedup should be obtained by reducing the number of shifts; first calculate `(p4 << 32) % m`,

```
for(i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
    p4 *= 2;
    if (p4 >= m) p4 -= m;
}
```

then all of `p2`, `p3` and the current value of `p4` need to be multiplied with 2<sup>32</sup> modulo `m`,

```
p4 += p3;
if (p4 >= m) p4 -= m;
p4 += p2;
if (p4 >= m) p4 -= m;
for(i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
    p4 *= 2;
    if (p4 >= m) p4 -= m;
}
s = p4+p1;
if (s >= m) s -= m;
return s;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform your multiplications in several stages. For example, say you want to compute X*Y mod n. Take X and Y and write them as X = 10^9*X_1 + X_0, Y = 10^9*Y_1 + Y_0. Then compute all four products X_i*Y_j mod n, and finally compute X = 10^18*(X_1*Y_1 mod n) + 10^9*( X_0*Y_1 + X_1*Y_0 mod n) + X_0*Y_0. Note that in this case, you are operating with numbers half the size of the maximum allowed.

If splitting in two parts do not suffice (I suspect this is the case), split in three parts using the same schema. Splitting in three should work.

A simpler approach is just to multiply the school way. It corresponds to the previous approach, but writing one number in as many parts as digits it has.

Good luck!