# How to calculate the result of the multiplication of two int64 numbers modulus another int64 number?

Tags: math, modulus, int64

Let a, b, and c be long long (int64) numbers, how to calculate (a*b)%c? The problem here is that you can't multiply (a%c)*(b%c) because it won't fit on an int64 variable. So, what can it be done?

Just in case it's helpful, I'm jusing C++.

Comment: FWIW, `%` is the remainder operator _not_ modulus.  Do you really need modulus or is `(a*b) >= 0 && c > 0` always true?

Comment: possible duplicate of [overflow possibilities in modular exponentiation by squaring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426557/overflow-possibilities-in-modular-exponentiation-by-squaring)

Comment: The question in the suggested duplicate doesn't look identical immediately, but it's the same problem, modular multiplication for large moduli.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an arbitrary precision library such as [gmp](http://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-General.html) to ensure that you'll never overflow your numerical type.

*or* you ensure that your multiplication will not overflow your type.  Without knowing more about your input, I can't really speculate on good ways to do that.

Or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115682/modulus-of-product-of-two-integers?rq=1) is very applicable to your task.